# install ruby 1.8.4 mac os x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, failed-installation

I am relatively new to Ruby and Rails, so please have patience with me. I I have RVM installed and my current version of Ruby is 1.9.3. and Rails 3.2.14 for the current apps I am working on. I am using Brew, GIT for version control,  and I also have Xcode installed.

Due to some work requirements, I am trying to install Ruby 1.8.4 on a mac os x Mountain Lion version 10.8.  I am planning to set up a Project .rvmrc file so I can also use Rails 1.3.4. 
When I run "rvm install ruby-1.8.4" I get this message:

**There is no checksum for 'http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/ruby-1.8.4.tar.gz' or 'ruby-1.8.4.tar.gz', it's not possible to validate it.
This could be because your RVM install's list of versions is out of date. You may want to
update your list of rubies by running 'rvm get stable' and try again.
If that does not resolve the issue and you wish to continue with unverified download
add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.**

Any suggestions? I was able to download the ruby- 1.8.4.tar.gz from another source, but I don't know how to make RVM install from a file.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: trying to make `ruby 1.8.4` work with `rvm` could be an exercise not worth the effort. `RVM` came into this world much later than `ruby 1.8.4`

Comment: Tank you for the prompt replies, I really appreciate it! I will give Vagrant a try, and will follow the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Eternal-Learner, RVM does not currently support 1.8.4, (you can get a list of the rubies that it can install using the `rvm list known` command).

That being said, per [this discussion](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/742) on their issue tracker from last year, you might be able to get them to try to implement it if you open up an issue.

Comment: Reviewing my old questions, thank you very much Jonathan, I really appreciate it. I ended up using the suggestion below by Depa and using Vagrant and Docker to setup a completely isolated environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you install [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) and then install the versions of Ruby and Rails you need directly from inside the Linux VM.

Since you'll have a VM set up exclusively for one project, you'll be able to install Ruby from source and skip RVM completely.

Comment: Reviewing my old questions, thank you Depa, I adopted using Vagrant and Docker  for different projects and it has really work out for me. One of the main attractive is that there is no conflict between configurations for different projects as well as no conflicts between dependencies for all of them.

Comment: Awesome setup. My answer was written before the rise of Docker, but now it makes a lot of sense to combine it with Vagrant.