# rails - Pass id parameter on a link_to / routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, link-to

I am trying to add a checkout link in order to direct a client to checkout view. 
I have a `ProductsController`, and an `OrdersController` where I defined the action for checkout. I am doing this because I set it so a product can have many orders.

---

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def checkout
    @product =  Product.find(params[:id])
  end
```

In my show.html.erb I added the line:

```
<%= link_to 'Contribute Now', order_checkout_path, :id => @product, :controller => "orders", :method => :get %>
```

And my routes look like:

```
root :to => 'products#index'
match '/products'               => 'products#index'
get 'order/checkout'

resources :products
resources :orders
```

After running rake routes I get:

```
           root        /                                   products#index
       products        /products(.:format)                 products#index
 order_checkout GET    /order/checkout(.:format)           order#checkout
                GET    /products(.:format)                 products#index
                POST   /products(.:format)                 products#create
    new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)             products#new
   edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)        products#edit
        product GET    /products/:id(.:format)             products#show
                PUT    /products/:id(.:format)             products#update
                DELETE /products/:id(.:format)             products#destroy
```

I have also defined a `checkout.html.erb` template.

After doing all that, I keep on getting an error of:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant OrderController
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `get 'orders/checkout'`, corresponding to the plural form of "order" used in your controller name.

Comment: Yes! It always get me with the plural.  If I change the routes to your suggestion, and then the line  <%= link_to 'Checkout', orders_checkout_path, :id => @product, :controller => "orders", :method => :get %>  , then I get another error:  Couldn't find Product without an ID

Comment: I noticed that you haven't upvoted or accepted any answers on your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480140/install-ruby-1-8-4-mac-os-x), so allow me to suggest that you might want to do that for both questions if you found the answers helpful. Amongst other things, it keeps others from spending time looking at a question that's already been addressed.

Comment: Hi Peter. I am very sorry,  I have don't have enough reputation to upvote answers. I did not see the follow up trail to previous question either. I wasn't sure either of how the Accept works. Thank you very much for the feedback, it is really appreciated.

Comment: No worries (and I keep forgetting about the upvote point requirement). I'm not sure what you mean by "follow up trail", but I see you found and accepted the answer from the earlier question. :-)

Comment: Thank you again, Peter :)!(And happy new year!) Back to task to "Couldn't find Product without an ID" ;)